# Best algorithm to make a smooth route through a raw set of GPS-points with some errors?

Tags: algorithms

We're developing a mobile application where one of it's functions is tracking user driving route.
The app simply pushes GPS-coordinates to the server, which stores them into a route.

Then we need to display that route gracefully on a map.

There are 2 problems:

1. Too many points to draw it all. I solve this by applying my variation of [RDP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)
2. GPS coordinates aren't ideal, sometimes there is an error up to 100-200 meters. Which causes loops or zigzags on the map and no one of the polyline simplification algorithms which I know can deal with it.

Do you know a way or an algorithm how to deal with errors in coordinates data to draw smooth routes?

The black is the actual polyline. The red is kind of my desired simplification.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).  This is a powerful way to smooth the data to eliminate noise, in a way that takes into account the dynamics of how physical objects move.